# Invalid template property or properties [Vpcname]

Tags: amazon-web-services, automation, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to create a stack with below templates. Same template worked without parameters.
When I Added parameters I got an  error which says -Invalid template property or properties
[Vpcname].
I am not sure what more to add as I have checked every aspect from amazon documentation.

```
{
"AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
"Description": "Here are some details about the template.",
"Vpcname": {
    "Description": "What do you want your VPC to be called as ?",
    "Type": "String",
    "Default": "fromCf"
},
"Resources": {
    "testvpc": {
        "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPC",
        "Properties": {
            "CidrBlock": "192.168.0.0/16",
            "EnableDnsHostnames": true,
            "EnableDnsSupport": true,
            "InstanceTenancy": "default",
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Key": "Name",
                    "Value": {
                        "Ref": "Vpcname"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "WebSubnet": {
        "Type": "AWS::EC2::Subnet",
        "Properties": {
            "AvailabilityZone": "ap-south-1a",
            "VpcId": {
                "Ref": "testvpc"
            },
            "CidrBlock": "192.168.0.0/24",
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Key": "Name",
                    "Value": "fromCfWebSub"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "AppSubnet": {
        "Type": "AWS::EC2::Subnet",
        "Properties": {
            "AvailabilityZone": "ap-south-1b",
            "VpcId": {
                "Ref": "testvpc"
            },
            "CidrBlock": "192.168.1.0/24",
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Key": "Name",
                    "Value": "fromCfAppSub"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I got it fixed Guys. I was not including  "Parameters" : { }  I should have put it this ways - "Parameters" : {"Vpcname": {
    "Description": "What do you want your VPC to be called as ?",
    "Type": "String",
    "Default": "fromCf"
}}

Comment: Can you add this as an answer and not as a comment? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got it fixed Guys. I was not including "Parameters" : { } I should have put it this ways - "Parameters" : {"Vpcname": { "Description": "What do you want your VPC to be called as ?", "Type": "String", "Default": "fromCf" }}